# Mediation Extensions vs Custom Handler in WSO2 API Manager

Tags: wso2-api-manager

In WSO2 API Manager, it supports light weight ESB for message mediation and it also supports REST Handler API. The question is in which cases we should use message mediation and in which cases we should create custom REST Handler? Because both of them look like have the same role.

Could anybody give me some advices in this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I have the answer. The main purpose of mediator is focus on processing the message while RESTHandler focus on the other things such as security, authentication, analytics,....